# Content going behind nav

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a problem with floats. I want a sidebar with the nav and text in the middle, but the text goes under the nav. I also tried float with clear and clear alone.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #93ece7;
}
.Wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}
.Header {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
}
.Header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.Header p {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 90%
}
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 71.9px;
  left: -39.9px;
  float: right;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}
.nav ul li {} .nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 10px;
  t;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #999;
  color: white;
}
.nav ul li span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 104%;
  background-color: #999;
}
.content {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!--start wrapper-->
<div class="Wrapper">

  <!--start header-->
  <div class="Header">
    <header>
      <h1>Tam &amp; Ils</h1>
      <p>knutselen en freubelen met tam &amp; ils</p>
    </header>
  </div>
  <!--end header-->

  <!--start nav-->
  <div class="nav">

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><span>Menu</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Over ons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><span>Producten</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ringen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kettingen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tassen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Freubles</a></li>
        <li><span>Tutorials</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ring Maken</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ketting Technieken</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tassen Hakken</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!--end nav-->

  <!--start content-->
  <div class="content">
    <main>
      <span>welkom op onze website</span>
      <p>welkom op deze website wij zij gek van kunstelen, freubelen en vooral lachen. OP deze website kun je dingen kopen en leren hoe je dingen die wij maken kunt maken</p>
    </main>
  </div>
  <!--end content-->

  <!--start footer-->
  <div class="footer">
    <footer>
      <p>copyright &copy; 2016 Youri Claes</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!--end footer-->

</div>
<!--end wrapper-->
```

Here is the [HTML](http://pastebin.com/vu9GHWx7)
and here is the [CSS](http://pastebin.com/9Df8PtcX).

Some other important information:

Editor: Brackets
System: win 7
Browser: Google Chrome

Comment: SO questions are supposed to help future readers, and links will go bad.  Please include all relevant code directly in your post (indent code 4 spaces or use the `{}` button to format as code).

Comment: JSFiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/o28zLgr6/

Comment: @JimGarrison if i did that it wouldn't let me post it because i had to much code

Comment: Then reduce the problem down to something manageable.  Remember the goal of SO is to be a resource for the future.  Answering your specific question is actually a secondary goal.  And, actually, if you are forced to trim the problem down you will likely discover the issue on your own.  If not, then the question and answers will be more likely to be of future value.

Comment: but can you guys help me please i can't ask a question util 7 days

Comment: `position: absolute`...

Comment: Consider using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Browser support is pretty good: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with your code but a few notes:

1. I recommend creating a jsFiddle demo like this: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/o28zLgr6/
2. When you apply `position:absolute` to an element, the float becomes irrelevant and the element will lose its place making it overlap others.
3. There is no need to set a height of a container that is supposed to be dynamic (the height will be automatic depending on content)
4. If you want to have a two-columns layout it is recommended to wrap both columns inside a container, this is the most basic structure

**CSS**

```
.wrapper { overflow:auto; }
.content { float:right; width:80%;}
.sidebar { float:left: width:20%; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that margins and paddings will break the layout because they add to the total width so try avoiding those or add `box-sizing:border-box;`

### In conclusion

here is a fixed version of your site with comments explaining what has been changed and why:

https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/o28zLgr6/1/

Since you did not wrap `.content` and `.sidebar` together in a container, I have cleared the floats using a div which has `clear:both` property.